# Configuring qgis map server to apache web server platform?

Tags: installation, qgis-server, apache

I installed Apache Web Server from OSGeo4W. here is the image shown below.[image]
 But when i put URL 
***http://localhost/cgibin/qgis_mapserv.fcgiSERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities***
i get an error which is shown below 
[image]
Can you help me how to work in web platform using qgis software?. i am new user of QGIS currently having a project on it.

Comment: is mod_fcgi enabled in your apache config file?

Comment: Was  enabling mod_fcgi the solution, or did something else fix the problem?  If so what was that additional configuration?

Comment: I reinstalled it from start point. When i put above link this time then it was working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try any of the debugging steps listed here: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial#Windows

It's a bit outdated, but they mention having to copy some files around to different directories than those specified by the default install

Comment: Thanks...  its working now... but i'm unable to connect the link to the QGIS browser from the server. Its giving an error. Can you give a solution for that?

Comment: I (or, better yet, the community) could try and help.  Can you post the error message?

Comment: I reinstall everything again from bottom and this time it works

Comment: Great. Glad you got it working.